# Typedef (alias) of an generic class

Tags: c++, templates

is it possible in C++ to create an alias of template class (without specifying parameters)?

```
typedef std::map myOwnMap;
```

doesn't work.

And if not, is there any good reason?

Comment: I think the best you can do is `using std::map;` to import `map` into the local namespace.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In C++98 and C++03 `typedef` may only be used on a complete type:

```
typedef std::map<int,int> IntToIntMap;
```

With C++0x there is a new shiny syntax to replace `typedef`:

```
using IntToIntMap = std::map<int,int>;
```

which also supports `template` aliasing:

```
template <
  typename Key,
  typename Value,
  typename Comparator = std::less<Key>,
  typename Allocator = std::allocator< std::pair<Key,Value> >
>
using myOwnMap = std::map<Key,Value,Comparator,Allocator>;
```

Here you go :)

Answer (score 14):

Template typedefs are not supported in the C++03 standard. There are workarounds, however:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyOwnMap {
  typedef std::map<std::string, T> Type;
};

MyOwnMap<int>::Type map;
```

Comment: @Uncle: He didn't say it was for length purposes, and his example takes the same number of keystrokes.

Answer (score 7):

This feature will be introduced in C++0x, called template alias. It will be looking like this:

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
using MyMap = std::map<Key, Value>
```

Answer (score 0):

For C++ lower 11 only one way

```cpp
template <...>
struct my_type : real_type<...> {}
```

Comment: Which mess ups non-trivial classes.

Comment: Nah, there is. A nested type within class template followed by a typedef, just like C++98 implementation of standard library does. But it defeats purpose  of expression to be short.

Comment: This will not be compatible with template aliasing and not to mention the terrible view. This"hack" is only way for writing crossstandart code for different platforms

Answer (score -1):

An alternative approach:

```
template <
        typename Key,
        typename Value,
        typename Comparator = std::less<Key>
>
class Map: public std::map<Key,Value, Comparator> {

};
```

Comment: That is not equivalent. That is subclassing, so you can't pass `std::map` to function accepting `Map`.

Comment: I did not say equivalent. It can be used in the compilers the above approach is not supported.